# AKS issues connecting to Azure Database for MySQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-mysql-database, azure-database-mysql

This has been previously working but stopped recently. I have a Wordpress container running in an AKS pod that connects to Azure Database for MySQL Server **Basic Pricing Tier**. Recently the container is unable to connect. I have tried to whitelist all IPs in the MySQL Connection Security to rule that out `0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255` but that did not seem to help.

When `exec` into the pod and install a MySQL client and try to connect to the MySQL Server I see an error:

```
ERROR 9009 (28000): Client connections to Basic tier servers through Virtual Network Service Endpoints are not supported. Virtual Network Service Endpoints are supported for General Purpose and Memory Optimized severs.
```

I don't understand why this was working in the past and stopped now. Is this error message correct and is it basically telling you either upgrade (which I don't think you can just do in the portal to scale up like you would do for SQL Server), or you will not be able to access the DB. To upgrade would I have to backup the DB, create a new server in the General Purpose Pricing Tier and restore, so no smooth Scale Up path?

I don't seem to have the VNet option in Azure Portal
[image]

**EDIT:**
I have since found [this post on microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20ec870e-a1e0-48cb-986a-6f91b0240a15/not-able-to-connect-to-azure-db-for-mysql-from-aks?forum=AzureDatabaseforMySQL) and what that is saying is that you have to upgrade to GP pricing tier. So going from **£19.805/month** to **£104.789/month**. Just wow.

**EDIT:**
The way to get it work with MySQL Basic Tier was to disable Service Endpoints in AKS VNet as suggested in the accepted answer. The problem was that the SQL Server was configured to use Service Endpoints. To get that going after removing the service endpoints I had to disable service endpoints in the SQL Server. Not too happy with that but I guess you can't have both, your Basic Tier MySQL Server and decent security. If you want both, you will have to pay :(

Comment: check if this helps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/911329c2-0dd4-4b64-b327-51a4522ac77e/fatal-server-is-not-configured-to-allow-ipv6-connections?forum=AzureDatabaseforPostgreSQL

Comment: what is different from this comment above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was never working, unless you were not using Service Endpoints. If you switch those off - it should resume working.

Comment: The way I made it work was to remove Microsoft.SQL service endpoint from AKS VNet. This allowed MySQL connection but broken SQL Server. For the SQL Server I had to configure Connection Policy Redirect and remove the VNet from Firewalls and virtual networks.